# What is a series of events called, similar to 'Festival' or 'Conference'

Tags: single-word-requests

Say, if an organisation is hosting several different events all under one name, and they could be at different time/locations and are generally open to a large audience, what are these *series of events* called? A few suitable words I can think of are *Festival*, *Tournament* or *Conference*.

A good example of this type of *events* would be the Fresher's Week during University term times, but you wouldn't call it a *Festival*, *Tournament* or *Conference*. So the question really could be: how would you categorise events like Fresher's Week, is it a *Festival*, *Tournament* or *Conference* etc?

Comment: when you say several events altogether at different locations, what do mean? The same event at multiple locations?

Comment: hi, usually a *conference* or *festival* would mean similar events under one roof, like all music, all business or all tech, but this would be different, this would be all different types of events hosted under one same name, hence I think Fresher's Week was a good example as you have sports/music/food/talks all during Fresher's Week.

Comment: Can you take the organization name, say ABC, and add Expo? An exposition covers anything ABC wants to include.

Comment: It may be called a "Welcome Week" or an "Orientation Week".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a **programme** (US program) [of events].

> programme (US program) noun
>
> 1A planned series of future events or performances.
>
> ‘a weekly programme of films’
>
> ‘the programme includes Dvořák's New World symphony’

[[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/programme)]

> 1.a. A listing of the order of events and other pertinent information for a public presentation.
>
> b. The presentation itself: *a program of piano pieces.*

[[AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/program)]